# How to Set Jdk version for Maven using Fedora alternatives

Tags: java, linux, maven, fedora

I wanted to change the jdk version used by Maven from 1.8 to 11 using `alternatives` on fedora.

```
$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.5.4 (Red Hat 3.5.4-4)
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_232, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.232.b09-0.fc29.x86_64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.18.16-300.fc29.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

I have 3 installed versions of java :

```
$ sudo alternatives --config java
[sudo] password for axione: 

There are 3 programs which provide 'java'.

  Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
   1           java-11-openjdk.x86_64 (/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.5.10-0.fc29.x86_64/bin/java)
   2           java-latest-openjdk.x86_64 (/usr/lib/jvm/java-13-openjdk-13.0.1.9-2.rolling.fc29.x86_64/bin/java)
*+ 3           java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64 (/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.232.b09-0.fc29.x86_64/jre/bin/java)
```

Answer (score 17):

The solution is in two parts :

1. Setting the jdk using alternatives by setting `java_sdk_openjdk`  :

   ```
   $ sudo alternatives --config java_sdk_openjdk
   ```
2. In the `~/.mavenrc` file setting the `JAVA_HOME` value by adding this line:

   ```
   export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-openjdk
   ```

**Explanation:**

1. The following command isn't the good one since it will change the java (JRE) version and not java (JDK) version.

   ```
    $ sudo alternatives --config java
   ```
2. `/usr/lib/jvm/java-openjdk` will point  to the new jdk every time we change `java_sdk_openjdk` using `alternatives`.

Answer (score 5):

***Edit Mar 20, 2024:***
I switched to using *sdkman* to manage my JDKs. I have different java projects that require different JDKs. I needed an easy way to switch JDK.

The `mvn` and `mvnw` commands will use whatever java it finds on your PATH. I use *sdkman* to set which JDK is on my path.

I don't rely on a `~/.mavenrc` or `/etc/java/maven.conf` anymore.

I install all available JDK OS packages:

```bash
sudo dnf install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel
sudo dnf install java-11-openjdk-devel
sudo dnf install java-17-openjdk-devel
sudo dnf install java-21-openjdk-devel
sudo dnf install java-latest-openjdk-devel
```

Install `sdkman` (https://sdkman.io/).

Register the installed JDKs with sdkman:

```bash
sdk install java system /usr/lib/jvm/java
sdk install java 8.0-system /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk
sdk install java 11.0-system /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk
sdk install java 17.0-system /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk
sdk install java 21.0-system /usr/lib/jvm/java-21-openjdk
sdk install java 22.0-system /usr/lib/jvm/java-22-openjdk
```

You can install additional JDKs, if desired.

```bash
sdk list java # List available jdk
sdk install java 21.0.2-tem # Install temurin java, for example
```

Set which one to use by default in new terminal sessions:

```bash
sdk default java 17.0-system
```

To switch to a different JDK
(sdk has good TAB completion. You don't need to memorize.)

```bash
sdk use java system  # Honor alternatives mechanism
sdk use java 8.0-system
sdk use java 11.0-system
sdk use java 17.0-system
sdk use java 22.0-system
sdk use java 21.0.2-tem
```

See also *asdf* (https://asdf-vm.com/). It is similar to *sdkman*. A similar approach using *asdf* may be used.

***Edit Nov 4, 2021:***
With the release of Fedora 35, you set the default jdk used by maven on a system-wide basis by installing one of the following binding packages:  `maven-openjdk8`, `maven-openjdk11`, or `maven-openjdk17`.

Do one of the following:

```bash
sudo dnf install maven-openjdk8 --allowerasing
sudo dnf install maven-openjdk11 --allowerasing
sudo dnf install maven-openjdk17 --allowerasing
```

These packages have the simple effect of setting `JAVA_HOME` accordingly in `/etc/java/maven.conf`.

A user may override this system-wide setting by setting JAVA_HOME in their `~/.mavenrc`, as outlined below. For example, setting it to `/usr/lib/jvm/java` will honor the JDK selected through the *alternatives* mechanism.

---

***Original answer:***

The `set_jvm` function in `/usr/share/java-utils/java-functions` does not respect `alternatives`.

Related bug report:

[1810950 – Maven package requires JDK 8 specifically and ignores alternatives](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1810950)

The following change to `/usr/share/java-utils/java-functions` would respect the jdk selected through the `alternatives` mechanism.

```
     case "${_prefer_jre}" in
         1|[Yy][Ee][Ss]|[Tt][Rr][Uu][Ee])
-            dirs="/usr/lib/jvm/jre-11-openjdk:/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk"
+            dirs="/usr/lib/jvm/jre:/usr/lib/jvm/java"
             ;;
         *)
-            dirs="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk:/usr/lib/jvm/jre-11-openjdk"
+            dirs="/usr/lib/jvm/java:/usr/lib/jvm/jre"
             ;;
     esac
```

[Update: Actually, there's [good reason](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/Decouple_system_java_setting_from_java_command_setting) for decoupling the version of java used by the distribution's java applications from what is selected through the *alternatives* mechanism.]

Alternatively, the approach by @Belkasmi is good, except I'd change `javac` instead of `java_sdk_openjdk`:

```
sudo alternatives --config java  # Set system default jre
sudo alternatives --config javac # Set system default java sdk
```

Then my `~/.mavenrc` has:

```
if [ -n "$JAVA_HOME" ]; then
  return
fi
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java
```

The test for non-empty `JAVA_HOME` ensures that a `JAVA_HOME` environment variable, if set, will take precedence.

Comment: There's no `maven-openjdk` package for java 21, does this mean there is an alternative way to do this now?

Comment: You could manually edit `/etc/java/maven.conf` or `~/.mavenrc` to set `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-21-openjdk`. I'm currently using `sdkman` to manage which JDK is on my PATH, and `mvn` and `mvnw` honors that. I added this to my answer just now.